# Checkbox true if two values match in ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Does anyone have an example, or know how to check a checkbox within an ng-repeat if two or more values are true?

Example:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in retults">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="((x.val1 == true) + (x.val2 == true))" />
<div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `{{`. Also it's `ng-repeat` not `ng-repeate` (no `e` at the end) and it's attribute value is not correct either. `value1` and so on don't exists. If providing example is good to provide an example that work, or does not but sort of valid. Otherwise it is just useless illustration. This is simple enough to do a small jsfiddle which would help people help you.

Comment: Now that you have updated your question how is `x.val1` and `x.val2` related to the statement `if two or more values are true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When true means 1 so add all of them and if greater than 1

```
<div ng-repeat="x in records">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="(x.x  + x.y  + x.z ) > 1" />{{x.x  + x.y  + x.z}}
<div>
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uu0vjb8h/)